# Can't set ZIndex in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have xaml code like this: [image]

Now what I want is: keep `Height` of `The Black Grid`, then set `Height` of `The Red WrapPanel` to `200`, but `The Red WrapPanel` is limited by `The Black Grid`. This will be like this: [image]
So how can I display full `The Red WrapPanel`? (Condition: Always keep `Height` of `The Black Grid`, it's not allowed to resize or do anything) I was tried with Canvas.ZIndex but still doesn't work. Thank you all!

Comment: Add controls over grid https://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html

Comment: @GrantWinney I want `The Red WrapPanel` must be a child of `The Black Grid` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using negative margins. like so:

```
<WrapPanel Background="Red" Height="200" Margin="0 0 0 -100"/>
```

Hope this help you.